# How to fix is not a function error when calling a function i created inside of a new function i created

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am creating two functions that will take an array and reverse the indeces and the characters like so

Input: ['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words'] 
Output: ['sdroW dezilatipaC', 'otatop', 'elppa']

the first function (reverseCharacters) I created reverses the characters of a string.

the second function (completeReversal) I am trying to create will completely reverse an array like the example above by calling the reverseCharacters function on each element of the array, then reversing the items in the array and adding them to a new empty array that will be displayed as the output.

in my completeReversal function I am able to reverse the elements in the array but can not call my reverseCharacters function to reverse the characters as well. I keep getting a "is not a function error"

I have tried converting the array into a string before calling the reverseCharacters function but seem to still get the is not a function error either way.

```
// Code reverseCharacters here:
function reverseCharacters(str){
  if (typeof str == 'string' ){
     return str.split('').reverse().join('');
  } else if (typeof str == 'number'){
     str = String(str);
     str = str.split('').reverse().join('');
     return Number(str);
  }
}

// Code complete()Reversal here:
function completeReversal(sampleArray){
    let emptyArray = [];
    sampleArray.reverse();

      for (i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++ ){
       emptyArray.push(sampleArray[i]);
       sampleArray.reverseCharacters();

  }
    return sampleArray;
}
    console.log(completeReversal(['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling function in wrong manner, since `sampleArray` is normal array and do not have any method called `reverseCharacters` on it's prototype, so you can't call it like this

```
sampleArray.reverseCharacters();
```

You need to call function like this

```
 emptyArray.push(reverseCharacters(sampleArray[i]));
```

Also return `emptyArray` variable from function

```js
// Code reverseCharacters here:
function reverseCharacters(str) {
  if (typeof str == 'string') {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
  } else if (typeof str == 'number') {
    str = String(str);
    str = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    return Number(str);
  }
}

// Code complete()Reversal here:
function completeReversal(sampleArray) {
  let emptyArray = [];
  sampleArray.reverse();

  for (i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
    emptyArray.push(reverseCharacters(sampleArray[i]));
  }
  return emptyArray;
}
console.log(completeReversal(['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words']));
```

---

An alternative and shorter solution can be this

```js
const completeReversal = (arr) => {
  return arr.reverse().map(str => str.split('').reverse().join(''))
}

console.log(completeReversal(['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words']));
```

Comment: @Katie you can mark as correct answer if it helped, [`What should I do when someone answers my question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var array = ['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words'];

var reverseArray = array.reverse();
var reversedStringArray = [];
reverseArray.map((d,i)=>{
  reversedStringArray.push(d.split('').reverse().join(''));
});

console.log(reversedStringArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```